# Allitems.aspx should disappear other members

Tags: sharepoint-designer, custom-list

I created a new custom list in my subsite. And I gave contribute permission other members for the site. Users can save new item in the list. They can see allitems.aspx.

Users are creating new item and then they are directed allitems.aspx and they can see other users items. But i don't want this. Because other items are secret. They should see their created item only.

I think this status's reason: give contribute permissions to other members. But if I don't give contribute permissions they can't the site and they got this error "Sorry, this site hasn't been shared with you.". But if I give contribute permissions they can see all items. How can I solve this problem. I want to other members can save new item and they can see items of created by their only. I don't want to appear all items to their.

Please give an advice.
Kind regards.

Answer (score 3):

AllItems.aspx is only the web page of a view.
But you want to restrict the items, which users can see.

Got to List Settings - Advanced Settings - Item-level Permissions.
Here you can select the options "Read items that were created by the user" and "Create items and edit items that were created by the user".

People with Full Access (Manage List Permission) can see all items.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks a lot @Fensterbank. It's solved. Thanks thanks thankss :))

Comment: Then mark this as the answer by clicking the little check icon so he get's credited for his work.